# how can i put the value of my list with v-model and value together?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i got empty value when i use `:value` and `v-model` together in the same element, I was trying to update some list in v-for,

here is the code

```
<input type="text"  :value="product.productName" v-model="product">
```

how can i get my value it and get some update from that value when client change it because I need to use that value for the update list?

i have some list to show the value on input so i should keep showing the value because i dont want it to be empty , u guys know how to update so we need the value keep on the input

Comment: Are you saying you have a dropdown with items in it, and you want to display the selected item in a text field?

Comment: `v-model` sets the field value, so it doesn't make sense to have a separate `value` attribute containing a different variable.  (The v-model for a text input should also be a plain string or number, not an object as it apparently is here.) It's not clear from your description what you're trying to do here, can you please clarify the question?